# Accessing misconfigured IP-camera

Tags: networking, ip-camera

Got a camera that is probably misconfigured. I know both IP and MAC and can do arp-ping, but can't do default ping and the camera is not accessible through web browser. My idea is that it has netmask or gateway misconfigured, since it has static IP. Is there any way I can access config interface by MAC address, since the login&password are also known?

All pings are done from the Mikrotik router to which all cameras connected by switches. No vlans involved by now etc.
[image: ARP-ping]

[image: default ping]

Router has IP 192.168.188.1/24

Wireshark

[image]

Comment: What ARP requests does the camera make when you try to ping it?

Comment: @user1686 how can I get that?

Comment: Using a packet capture tool like Wireshark or tcpdump. (For example, if the netmask is wrong and the camera thinks you're not in its subnet, it'll be making ARP requests for its configured gateway.)

Comment: @user1686 added wireshark screenshot to the post

Comment: Looks like the camera does correctly think that you're in its subnet (so the netmask is good enough and the gateway is irrelevant)... but it's ignoring your ARP replies for some reason. (188.288 is the Windows PC, I assume.) As a side note, your router also has a packet capture feature under `/tool sniffer`, e.g. `/tool sniffer quick interface=ether2 mac-address=00:0D:07:4A:02:D9`, in case it might be useful.

Comment: @user1686 yep but this doesn't show any useful information, and I confused now about Wireshark log. Seems that camera is working properly but nothing else happens to it

Comment: Almost any camera have hard reset knob. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the question and add vendor and model of the IP-camera (or provide a link to the manual, that's the first place to go for information what you can do with the camera).

> can do arp-ping

Please edit the question and include the arp-ping command and the results. (In particular, does the arp-ping IP match the IP you remember?)

> can't do default ping

Please edit the question and include the ping command, the PC interface configuration, and the error message. (It's possible the ping doesn't work for other reasons).

> netmask or gateway misconfigured

A misconfigured gateway doesn't matter as long as your PCs IP is in the subnet. The only potential problematic netmask configuration I could think of is `/32`, all others can be worked around by choosing the right IP address for your PC.

> Is there any way I can access config interface by MAC address

No.

There are direct layer 2 protocols (e.g. for LAN over powerline adapters), but I've never heard of any IP camera using them.

However, your camera may have a way to do a factory reset, which would mean a default IP address and gateway.

---

Ok, so the camera is answering ARPs for `192.168.188.151`, but doesn't reply to TCP on port 80, and doesn't reply to ICMP pings.

> No vlans involved by now etc.

What do you mean by "by now"? Did you have VLANs configured at some time? Is it possible that the camera is expecting a VLAN?

1. If you are root on the Microtik, you can do the following from the Microtik. If not, I'd connect the camera directly to a Linux PC for better control. (Configure a WLAN AP or use LAN on the Linux PC).
2. Give the PC the address `192.168.188.150` in case the netmask is misconfigured. That's one bit off.
3. Boot the camera with Wireshark running, see if it does DHCP. Some embedded systems also try a TFTP for firmware updates.
4. Try https on port 443 in addition to the port 80 you have tried.
5. Run `nmap` on the PC and to a portscan on the camera to see if there are **any** answers.
6. You know how the camera looks like, I don't know that. See if it has buttons (pressing them while booting may go to maintenance mode etc.). If you know a similar camera, please provide a link to a picture and/or a manual.

Comment: Adjusted question with known info. The camera model is unknown, but similar camera has a green interface with NV HD IP camera naming in web.